# How to get a value of href in modal window when we click the href?

Tags: javascript, php, popup, bootstrap-modal, codeigniter-3

I am trying to get a value in my pop up window when we click the a href.

**I use magnificPopup JavaScript**

Below code is my a href tag and I want the "data-stream" value to be get in the pop up window.

```
 <a class="popup-with-zoom-anim wiplay" id="<?=$entry->id?>" href="#small-dialog" data-detail-id ="<?=$entry->id?>" data-stream="<?=$demo_streamurl;?>">hello</a>
```

I need to value to be inserted in the src of the below code which comes in the pop up window.

```html
<div id="small-dialog" class="zoom-anim-dialog mfp-hide">
  <div class="popup-container">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-center popup-cont-container">
        <video id="vid1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls autoplay 
               width="640" height="364"
               data-setup='{ "techOrder": ["youtube"], "sources": [{ "type":  
                           "video/youtube", "src":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A7XdOyZIkko"}] }'>
        </video>
        <div class="video-info">
          <div id="wiVideoInfo">
            <div class="info-left">
              <div id="wiPlayerChannel" class="main-tag"></div>
              <div id="wiPlayerDate" class="datenTime"></div>
              <div id="wiPlayerInfo" class="video-info-main"> 
                <br>
                <span class="at"> </span></div><div id="wiPlayerhandler" class="at"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="info-right"> 
              <span><img src="<?=theme_url()?>images/eyeico.png">
                <a id="wiPlayerLives">    </a> Live viewers</span>
              <span><img src="<?=theme_url()?>images/heart.png"><a id="wiPlayerLikes">
                </a> Likes</span>
            </div>
          </div> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I do it either using JavaScript or using PHP?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a code like below, as given in the [docs § Varying modal content based on trigger button](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target):

```
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget); // Button that triggered the modal
  var stream = button.data('stream'); // Extract info from data-* attributes
  var modal = $(this);
  modal.find(".video-js").attr("data-setup", '{ "techOrder": ["youtube"], "sources": [{ "type": "video/youtube", "src": "' + stream + '"}] }');
});
```

So the `stream` inside the function will have the `data-stream`'s value. You need to set whatever you wanna set. Let me know if this works. `:)`

Comment: How about using `this` context instead of `event` object ?

Comment: @Rayon How do you do that in such an event?

Comment: @gitu You just need to add this extra code. That's all. Change the `#exampleModal` to `#small-dialog`. That's all.

Comment: @PraveenKumar 
I am using magnificpopup
What about the video play tag?
is it same as 
  <video id="vid1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls autoplay width="640" height="364"
     data-setup='{ "techOrder": ["youtube"], "sources": [{ "type": "video/youtube", "src": ""}] }'>
    </video>
        
        or 
  <video id="vid1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls autoplay width="640" height="364"
     data-setup=''>
    </video>

Comment: @gitu Yes. It is the same.

Comment: @PraveenKumar it is not working for me.i used   <video id="vid1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls autoplay width="640" height="364" data-setup='{ "techOrder": ["youtube"], "sources": [{ "type": "video/youtube", "src": ""}] }'> </video>

Comment: @PraveenKumar i have 10 youtube urls which should play random on each pop up show.This is an alternative solution for my demo purpose.do you have any code?

Answer (score 0):

1. get the data-stream value from id $entry->id?
2. replace the **data-stream** value by data-stream

   ```
   var data_stream = $('#vid1').attr('data-setup');
   dt.val(dt.val().replace("**data-stream**",
   $('#'<?=$entry->id?).attr('data-stream').val()));
   ```

Comment: Is this an answer?

Comment: should work, that's an abstract idea.. many not be able to copy paste